# Resteasy Bean Validation Not Being Invoked

Tags: java, spring, resteasy, bean-validation

## Problem Background

I have a Resteasy service that uses Spring through Resteasy's `SpringContextLoaderListener`.  This is built on Resteasy version `3.0-beta-6`.

I would like to use bean validation on the incoming requests, but I can not get Resteasy to call the validator.  It acts like there is no validation configured and simply passes the method the invalid input object.

## Question

1. How do I enable bean validation in Resteasy?

## What I've Tried

I have done the following:

1. Annotated my resource class with `@ValidateRequest`
2. Annotated the method parameter with `@Valid`
3. Annotated the constraints on my input class.
4. Added a dependency on `resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider`

#### Resource:

```
@Named
@Path("users")
@ValidateRequest
public class UserResource 
{
    /**
     * 
     * @param user
     * 
     * curl -x POST http://localhost:7016/api/1.0/users
     * 
     */
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response createUser(@Valid User user)
    {
        //User creation logic here.
    }
}
```

#### User POJO:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "user_id",
    "user_name",
    "email"
})
public class User
{
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    @NotNull(message = "Username must be provided")
    private String username;

    @Email(message = "Invalid email address.")
    private String email;

    //Getters and Setters Removed for Brevity
}
```

#### POM Entry for Validation:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The `resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider` dependency brings in the `HibernateValidatorContextResolver` and its associated `HibernateValidatorAdapter`.

---

## Update (6/18/2013):

I reverted the Resteasy version in my pom to `2.3.5.Final` and bean validation started working without any code changes.

Answer (score 1):

Running with Resteasy '3.0.6.Final' and Spring '4.1.0.RELEASE'.

The 'resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider' does not evaluate the @Valid annotated params. Using the 'resteasy-validator-provider-11' makes everything work and as a bonus is using Hiberbate validator '5.0.1.Final' instead of needing a Hibernate validator version 4 when using the 'resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this:

**Providing a ValidatorAdapter to RESTEasy**

RESTEasy will try to obtain an implementation of ValidatorAdapter through a ContextResolver provider in the classpath. We can provide RESTEasy with an implementation like follow:

```
@Provider
public class MyValidatorContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidatorAdapter> {

   @Override
   public ValidatorAdapter getContext(Class<?> type) {
      return new MyValidator(); 
   }

}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't that only for custom validators?  I have added the resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider dependency to my project which has the HibernateValidatorAdapter and the context resolver for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.Providers defined in your war.

You can use the hibernate validator provided with resteasy-3.0.

Check chapter 48, of the resteasy documentation :

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#JBoss AS 6

Comment: How is this different than registering them in web.xml under the resteasy.providers context parameter?