# Resteasy Bean Validation Not Working on Remote Server

Tags: rest, jetty, resteasy, bean-validation

I have a problem similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005292/resteasy-bean-validation-not-being-invoked).

I am using RESTEasy within a standalone Jetty application. When I start the application locally and call a service (e.g. *localhost:16880/rest/user/login*) bean validation works fine, i.e. I get validation errors like this:

```
[PARAMETER]
[UserService#login(arg0).appKey]
[app_key may not be null or empty]
[]
```

However, when I deploy my application to a remote host and call the same service (e.g. *remotehost:16880/rest/user/login*) bean validation is not invoked at all.

I am using the `@ValidateRequest` annotation for the service and `@Valid` annotation for the bean parameter.

My Resteasy version is 3.0.13.Final, though I have tried earlier versions as well. I have tried to write my custom validator, but that didn't work either.

I am puzzled why the validation works locally, but not on remote server. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Jetty as *standalone* server, you have to define RESTEasy validation providers where you define `ServletContextHandler`. Note that in standalone server there is no container to scan for `@Provider` classes and to activate them, so you must do it manually.

I expect that you create and start your server app something like:

```
//create a server listening at some port
Server server= new Server(port);

//add server handlers
HandlerList handlers= new HandlerList();
initHandlers(handlers);
server.setHandler(handlers);

//start the server
server.start();
```

In `initHandlers` you must have defined your RESTEasy support:

```
public void initHandlers(List<HandlerList> handlers) {
    //define root context handler
    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler= new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/");
    handlers.addHandler(servletContextHandler);

    //define RESTEasy handler
    ServletHolder restServlet= new ServletHolder(new HttpServlet30Dispatcher());

    //since this is a standalone server, somewhere you have to define RESTful services and Singletons
    restServlet.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.exampleapp.MyRestApplication");
    restServlet.setInitParameter("resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix", "rest");

    servletContextHandler.addServlet(restServlet, "rest/*");
}
```

So what is left to do now is to add Validation provider as init parameter:

```
restServlet.setInitParameter("resteasy.providers", "org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.ValidatorContextResolver,org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper");
```

On this link I tried to find the name of the validator providers: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/Validation.html

> RESTEasy obtains a bean validation implemenation by looking in the available META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.Providers files for an implementation of ContextResolver

So it does not say what, but says where. Now open the "resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider-3.*.*.*.jar (from Eclipse -> Maven dependencies or manually unzip) and look into META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers It says:

> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.hibernate.ValidatorContextResolver
>   org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper

If you don't have this dependency, then add it to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

One more note: that at the same place where you described validation providers, you also add other providers, if you happen to need them (such as JacksonJaxbJson, etc).

Comment: Perfect, manually registering the providers (by calling `setInitParameter`) was the key here. In addition to that, I had to add **expression language dependencies** to my pom file. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386771/javax-validation-validationexception-hv000183-unable-to-load-javax-el-express) for more details.